# how to change the custom attribute value using angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, material-design, angularjs-controller, angular-material

i have used material design class in my app.

```
<div flex="30" flex-sm="100" ng-repeat="shortListLoad in user.shortListLoads">
 <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings" ng-click="checkShortList(shortListLoad.id)">
   <md-icon md-font-icon='icon-favorite' style='color:red'></md-icon>
 </md-button>
</div>
```

I need to change the **"md-font-icon"** attribute value to **'icon-favorite-outline'** while calling the checkShortList() function in controller.

How to do this please suggest a best way in angularjs  rather than jquery???

Comment: you mean on click of button change attr value

Comment: yes bro it'l be handle in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `flag` value in your controller method `checkShortList`.
Keep a flag in each of the `shortListLoad` object.

```
//initially
 angular.forEach(user.shortListLoads,function(res){
    res.flag = true;
 }); 

 $scope.checkShortList = function(shortListLoad,id){
     shortListLoad.flag = false;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
    <md-button class="md-icon-button md-primary" aria-label="Settings" ng-click="checkShortList(shortListLoad,shortListLoad.id)">
         <md-icon md-font-icon="{{shortListLoad.flag ? 'icon-favorite' : 'icon-favorite-outline'  }}" style='color:red'></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Comment: Please see the edited one, it's under "ng-repeat"  how to change specific one?

Comment: $scope.flag = true; //initially it's not take as initial value.
flag initial value is false while loading the page

Comment: did you get my question??

Comment: yes man it's working ... can you say when this angular.forEach() method is calling? it's while page loading?

Comment: just put it as it is in your controller

Comment: yah i put , but i actually wish to know that how to 'flag' appends happening in angular.forEach()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95676/discussion-between-nglover-and-user3391137).